# Adjective for the major threat of an imminent cyber attack

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am making a presentation in which I wish to say that I am going to talk about the ______ of present-day cyber security threats.

I want to fill the blank with an adjective which describe two properties of the threats:

(1) **Imminence:** They (cyber attacks) are not something which can be ignored thinking they might occur in future; as they are occurring NOW in present time *(**imminent** would be the word?)*

(2) **Intensity of Impact:** They (cyber attacks) are so intense/devastating that they can not be ignored, as they can have devastating effect on national and individual security.

(3) **Ubiquity:** Cyber security can not be ignored as cyber security is involved in almost all pasts/aspects of our lives (as wherever there is technology, there is cyber security involved)

Comment: You are requesting an adjective, but your example is set up for a noun.

Comment: Yes, well, "gonna talk about" sounds very informal. You need to find an English (language) editor. We don't do editing here.

Comment: "in my presentation" is redundant, surely? If you really want to save words, cut it out.

Answer (score 1):

1. "Imminent" means *about* to happen; it describes the future, albeit the near future, so it isn't a good choice for your meaning of "currently in process."
2. Some of your sentiments are covered by the phrase "clear and present danger." The phrase [originated in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clear_and_present_danger) a Supreme Court ruling about free speech, and was popularized by a 1989 Tom Clancy novel and subsequent movie.
3. Sometimes you can't find one perfect word that happens to cram in three very distinct connotations. What's wrong with using three words?

> These cyber attacks cannot be ignored, because of their immediacy, impact, and ubiquity.

... or, better yet, use a more active construction:

> We cannot ignore these cyber attacks, because they are currently underway, they impact our security severely, and they permeate all aspects of our lives.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest **urgency**.

> *urgency* [noun] [mass noun]
>
> 1 Importance requiring swift action.
>
> - *the discovery of the ozone hole gave urgency to the issue of CFCs*
> - *these are the grave urgencies facing us*

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/urgency)]

> - *The attack this past week by radical Islamists on the gas fields in Algeria shows the urgency of the threat.*

[[The New York Times via Ludwig](https://ludwig.guru/s/urgency+of+the+threat)]

Of course, **seriousness** is a synonym, perhaps with not quite the same punchiness:

> *seriousness*
>
> (1) the degree to which something is bad or dangerous
>
> - *Officials were downplaying the seriousness of the situation.*
>
> The quality of being serious, severe or extreme: **severity**,
> **gravity**
>
> (2) the fact or quality of being important and deserving attention
>
> - *the extreme seriousness of national security*

[[Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/seriousness)] [reformattted]

And of the synonyms listed, **gravity** also fits with the example sentence:

'I am going to talk about the **urgency** / **seriousness** / **gravity** of the present-day cyber security threats in my presentation.' Only the first directly stresses the time element involved.